# How to test onclick in this object without id

Tags: watir, watir-webdriver

I'm trying to test the on-click on this object but i don't know how to get to i'm, anyone can help me?

```
<a onclick="addRemoveSelectedNumber(this);">
<img src="../../static/images/sec_core/delete.png">
</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an XPath expression to find your element.

```
browser.link(:xpath, "//path/to/my/element/a").click
```

See: http://wiki.openqa.org/display/WTR/XPath

Answer (score 3):

Two intuitive alternatives:

```
browser.link(:onclick=>"addRemoveSelectedNumber(this);").click
```

You may have to escape the slashes in this one...

```
browser.image(:src=>"../../static/images/sec_core/delete.png").click
```